Is $T_{initial} = T_{permuted}$ tallied as significant or insignificant in permutation testing?
Assume that I perform a permutation test to check that two distributions are the same, and the output test statistics are always integers.  There is no single direction so the test will be two tailed. Thus I assert $H_0$ as 'same' and perform several thousand trials.
The initial un-permuted test statistic is $T_{initial}$, and the permuted test statistics are $T_{permuted}$.
Q. Is $T_{initial} = T_{permuted}$ tallied as significant or insignificant?
I ask as an implementation of NIST SP 800-90B randomness testing has the following in it:-
if((C[0] + C[1] <= 5) || C[1] + C[2] <= 5){ 

where C[0] is less than, C[1] is equals and C[2] is greater. This is effectively a 2 tailed test with α = 0.001 and 10,000 permutations. So you can see that NIST considers that if un-permuted and permuted test statistics are equal, that is significant. That seems contrary to common sense as equal test statistics indicate to me no difference.

Your post is a little unclear. This is for computing a p-value?

@Glen_b Yes, it is.

Then quite literally, see the definition of p-value. What definition do you have for it?

@Glen_b Surely if you permute and test, and the test statistic is the same, it cannot suggest rejecting the null hypothesis of sameness. This specifically applies to integer test statistics.  Remember that integers have two edges in a Normal numbers line. If you mangle the data and it still tests the same, it must be insignificant/from the same distribution. Yet the NIST snippet suggests so, yet that doesn’t make sense to me. Can anyone reasonable help with my confusion?  It’s not home work :-)

I am sorry, I don't understand what you just said there.

Sorry, my intention was not to be condescending. I used the opportunity to write an answer pointing out the important role of tags , tag wikis, and tag wiki excerpts on this site, many users are unaware! so wanted to do some propaganda. When answering late now, that is simply because this days I am more time in my garden than at my computer. As for your last comment, as with @Glen_b I do not understand. Test statistics being integers play no role in the definition of p-value?

Your question has the tag p-value. Reading its tag wiki excerpt you find

In frequentist hypothesis testing, the
-value is the probability of a result as extreme (or more) than the observed result,  ...

I think that should enable you to answer your own question?

+1 it's literally the answer to the question. By the definition of p-value (sometimes alternatively phrased as 'at least as extreme') you count the ones that are exactly as extreme as the observed one - and indeed, you should normally count the observed (initial) one in there itself.
